# Hibernate - How to add property to projection list , if another property value is null?

Tags: hibernate, formula, criteria, projection, notnull

How to have if condition with Restrictions/projections.?

I am having pojo(for table Student) this way,

```
class student
{
@Id
    @Column(name = "SSN", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String SSN;

    @Column(name = "Badge")
    private String Badge;

    @Column(name = "Color")
    private String Color;

    @Formula(value = " concat(Badge, '', Color) ")
    private String BadgeColor;

    //getters  and setters.
}
```

Data for these columns in student table is this way,

```
ssn  badge color
===  ====  ======
118  LB     22

117  GAAG   33
```

I am fetching criteria.list() from the table using projections this way,

```
   // setup projections for column selection
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
    List<String> requestedColumns=[ssn,badge,color];
            if (requestedColumns != null && requestedColumns.size() > 0) {
                ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
                for (String column : requestedColumns) {                
                    pl.add(Projections.property(column));
                }
                cr.setProjection(pl);
            } 
    return cr.list();
```

So,I am getting output this way,

```
[[118, LB, 22]//[SSN,BADGE,Color]
[117, GAAG, 33]//[SSN,BADGE,Color]
```

This is ok. But what I want is , I want to concat badge&color and show it.

And that is the reason why I have added @Formula to my pojo above shown.

And then, i have added badgecolor column to projection list this way,

```
List<String> requestedColumns=null;
        if (requestedColumns != null && requestedColumns.size() > 0) {
            ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
            for (String column : requestedColumns) {                
                if(column.equalsIgnoreCase("Badge"))
                {                                        
                     pl.add(Projections.property("BadgeColor"));
                }               
                else
                    pl.add(Projections.property(column));
            }
            cr.setProjection(pl);
        }
```

Now I am getting data this way,

```
[[118, LB22, 22]//[SSN,BadgeColor,Color]
**[117, null, 33]//[SSN,BadgeColor,Color]**
```

Issue is, If BadgeColor==null as above then I need to get badge data itself over there,.

ie, expected output is,

```
 [[118, LB22, 22]//[SSN,BadgeColor,Color]
    **[117, GAAG, 33]//[SSN,badge,Color]**//
```

I tried adding restriction `ISNOTNULL` this way while adding into projection list,

```
if(column.equalsIgnoreCase("Badge"))
                {           
                    **cr.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("BadgeColor"));**               
                     pl.add(Projections.property("BadgeColor"));
                }               
                else
                    pl.add(Projections.property(column));
```

But it is completely removing all the rows with BadgeColor=null values from list. SO I AM getting only on record as output.

[[118, LB22, 22]//[SSN,BadgeColor,Color]

Can anyone help me in this issue?

What I want is,

```
   If this formula calculated BadgeColor column value != null - add BadgeColor property to projection.
else if formula calculated BadgeColor column value == null - then add badge property to projection.
```

please help..

Answer (score 1):

you must convert the NULL values with empty string by wrapping it in COALESCE.

change formula code to this:

```
@Formula(value = "concat( COALESCE(Badge,''), ' ',   COALESCE(Color,''))")
private String BadgeColor;
```

Comment: Is there any formula to count all the rows in a table?

Comment: @Riasat yes there is. you should in formula value put query that count table rows. like to this `@Formula("(select count(*) from ...")`